# Check for proper e-mail format in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

The E-mail address is supposed to be in the format X@Y.Z and X, Y may be latin characters or numbers while Z may only contain latin letters. X, Y and Z are supposed to be non-empty strings.

I'm currently using `CHECK (Email LIKE '%_@__%.__%')` but it still allows numbers in Z and special characters.

Please note that this is a somewhat constructed task for learning purposes and not optimally suited to the real world.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email and remember that arvo@local is pretty valid address too :)

Comment: Looks like Unicode foreign characters are allowed as well. I cannot imagine creating a Unicode email address, half the web would probably not accept it, but technically it is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement as you described it you can use the operator [`GLOB`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_and_match_operators) to construct the `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(
  email TEXT,
  CHECK (
    email LIKE '%_@_%._%' AND
    LENGTH(email) - LENGTH(REPLACE(email, '@', '')) = 1 AND
    SUBSTR(LOWER(email), 1, INSTR(email, '.') - 1) NOT GLOB '*[^@0-9a-z]*' AND
    SUBSTR(LOWER(email), INSTR(email, '.') + 1) NOT GLOB '*[^a-z]*'
  )
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=83b858edcc9948365503607c89e4ed0c).